# How can I fetch data from inside a node which the database.ref is listening to in my Firebase real-time database using cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Below is a part of the function that I'm using to fetch data.

```
functions.database.ref(/path/{pushId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot,context)=>{
        const original = snapshot.val();
```

Below is the structure of my DB.

```
"path":{
    "$pushId":{
            "products": {
                         "0" : {
                               "cabinet": "cabinet1"
                               },
                         "1" : {
                               "cabinet": "cabinet2"
                               }
                         }
              }
}
```

How can I fetch the value of each cabinets stored inside products node insdie the path/{pushId} that my function is listening to?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the database path pattern in your function doesn't match the structure of your database.  There is no leading "/path" in your database.  Are you sure this function even triggers correctly?  If it does, have you tried simply logging `original` to see what it contains?

Comment: The function is working properly.
I've edited my question. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Back to my second question: have you tried simply logging `original` to see what it contains? That might help you figure out how to proceed.

Comment: Yes. Tried that as well.
I've also tried original.products and the output looked somewhat like this:

map[cabinet:cabinet1 ]map[cabinet:cabinet2]

Comment: Maybe you would like to edit the question to show the exact output, and the lines of code you used to do it?  Anything you can provide would be helpful.  We need to be able to see what you see.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
functions.database.ref(/path/{pushId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot,context)=>{
        const original = snapshot.val();

        Object.keys(original).forEach(key => {
          const product = original[key];
          console.log(product.cabinet);
        }
}
```